# How can i check if multiple divs have been clicked in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to "track" if all divs have been clicked. If all divs have been clicked something should happen. This can only happen when all divs have been clicked.

http://jsbin.com/cawukapumi/1/
This is what i've gathered so far. 
Any help is more then appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".masterobject").click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked, true');
                 });
    

if ($('#obj1').data('clicked') && $('#obj2').data('clicked') && $('#obj3').data('clicked') && $('#obj4').data('clicked') && $('#obj5').data('clicked') ) {
    console.log( "all has been clicked" );
    }
});
```

```css
.masterobject {
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
z-index: 2;
}

#obj1 {
width: 50px;
height: 60px;
top: 25%;
left: 19%;

}

#obj2 {
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
top: 12%;
left: 84%;
}

#obj3 {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
top : 66%;
left : 73%;
}

#obj4 {
top: 54%;
left: 28%;
width: 60px;
height: 70px;

}

#obj5 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
top: 45%;
right: 13%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masterobject" id="obj1"></div>
    <div class="masterobject" id="obj2"></div>
    <div class="masterobject" id="obj3"></div>
    <div class="masterobject" id="obj4"></div>
    <div class="masterobject" id="obj5"></div>
```

Comment: Put your HTML and JS in the question. Don't just link off site.

Comment: Loop throguh on all of your divs, and the the id of them into an array. Create another embty array, called, `clickedDivs`.  When a div clicked, check is there the id of it in `clickedDivs`. If not, then `push` it. Every time, you can compare the two arrays. If they are the same, then all div has clicked.

Comment: BTW: your syntax here is wrong: `$(this).data('clicked, true');`, it should be: `$(this).data('clicked', true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class, see if its count matches the count of items:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".masterobject").click(function() {

        $(this).addClass("clicked");

        if ($(".masterobject").length == $(".clicked").length)
             alert("all clicked");

    });
});
```

Comment: A nice solution although you are searching the DOM twice for each click to build up the list of `.masterobject` and `.clicked`.

Comment: True although the former can be cached easily enough.

Comment: And you could, after caching the former, restrict the search for `.clicked` like this `masterobjects.filter(".clicked").length` because you know that all the `.clicked` objects must be a subset of the `.masterobject`.

Comment: Your answer worked beautifully. Really an eye opener for me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you could do something like this:

```js
var clickers = $(".clicker");
clickers.on("click", function() {
  $(this).data("clicked", true);
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
  var all = true;
  clickers.each(function() {
    all &= $(this).data("clicked");
    return all;
  });
  if (all) {
    alert("all clicked!");
  }
});
```

```css
.clicker {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
  }

#div1 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
#div2 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 130px;
}
#div3 {
  left: 130px;
  top: 10px;
}
#div4 {
  left: 130px;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clicker" id="div1"></div>
<div class="clicker" id="div2"></div>
<div class="clicker" id="div3"></div>
<div class="clicker" id="div4"></div>
```

What we are doing is for every div with the class `clicker` we bind a `click` handler that will get the `clicked` property of this div. Then we check to see if all divs with this class have been clicked and pop an alert if they have.

Note: I added a class so you can tell when you've clicked a div (in my example, they now turn blue). You could actually use that instead of a data property by using `.hasClass`.

Answer (score 0):

1 approach: You'll need to check if all the divs are clicked each time one is clicked. So, I'd loop through each of your `div`'s, see if the attribute is set... and if not, set a standard boolean var to false.

Something like the following...

```
var allClicked = true;
$('.masterobject').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')){
        allClicked=false;
        return false;
    }
});

if(allClicked){
    alert('yay!');
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kokumohohe/2/edit?output

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ugly, but you can do something like:

```
div1 = "1";
div2 = "1";
div3 = "1";
divSum = div1 + div2 + div3;
console.log(divSum);

$("#div1").click(function() {
    div1 = "2";
    check();
});
$("#div2").click(function() {
    div2 = "2";
    check();
});
$("#div3").click(function() {
    div3 = "2";
    check();
});

function check () {
    divSum = div1 + div2 + div3;
    if (divSum = 222) {
        alert("TAdaaahh!");
    };
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xdpyx3rx/1/

Comment: "*a bit ugly*" might be an understatement. Also you are only actually checking on the third div, you need to check on every div because you don't (presumably) know what order they will be clicked in.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach using combination of jQuery and `getElementsByClassName` method, which allows you not to requery DOM on each click taking advantage of live NodeList:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var clicked = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked');
    var $masterObjects = $(".masterobject").click(function() {

        $(this).addClass("clicked");

        if ($masterObjects.length === clicked.length) {
             alert("all clicked");
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/wepoqumita/1/

Comment: Ugh! That seems like it would be a nightmare to maintain. You are relying on all future maintainers understanding that `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* list. Feels too clever for it's own good.

Comment: :) Well I use this pattern frequently, and it's pretty cool. Why do live NodeList exist at all if you should not use their main feature? No magic here. And I think that this is very basic stuff, not so hard to understand actually.